# Executing UpKeep command until Balance reaches 0

Tags: chainlink

[We are looking](https://github.com/CryptoQueen2/Rent_an_NFT-BE) to have `performUpkeep` run until the wallet balanace hits 0 on a set of Chainlink Keepers.

We managed to try out an error-less execute on remix with a plausible syntax. However would still like to know if the solution is right or over-engineered.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

interface KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData);
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external;
}

contract Counter is KeeperCompatibleInterface {

    uint public counter;    // Public counter variable

    // Use an interval in seconds and a timestamp to slow execution of Upkeep
    uint public immutable interval;
    uint public lastTimeStamp;    

    constructor(uint updateInterval) {
      interval = updateInterval;
      lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
      counter = 0;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        performData = checkData;
    }

    function balance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;

    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata) external override {
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        require(address(this).balance > 0);
       
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. When asking questions if you keep them minimalistic. I'll answer this question at face value, but please update your question to resemble the minimalistic question you have. Take a read here on how to ask a well-formatted question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an upkeep to occur untill the balance reaches 0, you'd need to quantify so in the `checkUpkeep` and `performUpkeep`, for example:

```js
    function checkBalance() public view returns(bool){
        return address(this).balance >= 0;
    } 
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /** checkData **/ ) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData) {
        upkeepNeeded = checkBalance();
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata) external override {
        require(checkBalance(), "Balance not 0");
    }
```